# Checking an array for equal values

Tags: java

I'm creating a programme that generates a sequence of numbers and stores their values into an array of doubles. Basically it's a calculator that will randomly output the roll of 4 dice, with a boolean test condition to check if all four dice values are the same. A victory message will then appear.

Could anyone assist me with writing the code for this? I'm pretty new to Java :) and yes, it's on Java.

The method for the strings is concrete too so i don't need to worry about it.

```
private int[] sequence = { 1, 1, 1, 1 }; // this is just an example
...
public boolean areTheseDiceEqual()
{
// No idea how to go about this
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess it should be noted that the code should compare each value in the sequence so it'd use some kind of for loop. If anyone answers this, could you provide an explanation as to how you achieved the result? I would like to learn!

Comment: Hint: `sequence[0]` is the first element, `sequence[1]` the second, etc; You should use `int` here, not `double`; you can compare two `int` for equality with `==`

Answer (score 3):

Try iterating through the array:

```
double previous = sequence[0];
for(int i =1; i < sequence.length; i++){
    if(sequence[i] != previous) 
         return false;
    previous = sequence[i];
}
return true;
```

This should work for arrays of much more than 4 elements if required.

Comment: This worked like a charm, and i understand it too. It's clever. I often find it hard to visualize exactly what i want to do, yet people like yourself manage to reel it off your head so quickly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can store the variable that is in the first position of the array and return false as soon as any of the values in the later positions don't have the same value.

```
public boolean areTheseDiceEqual() {
    double firstDie = -1;
    for(oneDie : sequence) {
        firstDie = (firstDie == -1 ? oneDie : firstDie);
        if(firstDie != oneDie) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I also really like this answer too ^ :)

Comment: Good. If sequence has no length, this way will not throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean areTheseDiceEqual(double[] s) {
    return (s[1] == s[2] && s[2] == s[3] && s[3] == s[4])
}
```

I guess there's no more elegant way.

Comment: what if only `s[1]` and `s[3]` are equal?

Comment: @NikosM. then the expression is `false`

Comment: Which I think is what the OP was asking for, despite the title.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to look at previous dice as the 1st difference is sufficient to return false so you can write it simply like that :

```
private boolean areTheseDiceEqual(){
    int firstShot=shots[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < shots.length; i++) {
        if(firstShot!=shots[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Tested with 4 jUnit tests, it just works :)

```
@Test
public void test1(){
    shots(1,2,3,4);
    assertFalse(areTheseDiceEqual());
}

@Test
public void test2(){
    shots(1,1,1,1);
    assertTrue(areTheseDiceEqual());
}

@Test
public void test3(){
    shots(1,1,1,4);
    assertFalse(areTheseDiceEqual());
}

@Test
public void test4(){
    shots(1,2,2,2);
    assertFalse(areTheseDiceEqual());
}

public void shots(int... shots){
    this.shots=shots;
}
```